# In supernatural how did Charlie escape?

Tags: supernatural, the-wizard-of-oz

In Season 10 of Supernatural, Episode 11 - There's No Place Like Home:

> Charlie returns from Oz

How does she get back? Did I miss that bit or does she just appear?

> The door to Oz is in the bunker, so unless there's multiple doors they can access, or the Wizard did them *both* a favour in getting back then I don't see how it's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Dorothy, the Key to Oz works in any door (emphasis mine):

> **Dorothy:** It's the key to Oz. There are magical ways into Oz - tornado, eye of a hurricane, whirlpool - but **this key will turn any locked door into a portal to Oz.** Insert key, twist, and presto, you're in Oz.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Supernatural* Season 9 episode 4 "Slumber Party"](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=9.04_Slumber_Party_(transcript))</sub></sup>

How this works when going from Oz to our world is never discussed, but presumably it works similarly.

The quote above indicates that there are ways *into* Oz that don't require the key, which presumably means there are other ways *out* of Oz as well. "Slumber Party" makes a point of saying that the Ruby Slippers don't work that way, but the Wizard of Oz in "There's No Place Like Home" appears to use a spell that transports him from Oz to any location in our world, and he presumably had a plan to get back<sup>1</sup>:

> **Good!Clive Darrow:** Without the key to Oz there's no way we can get back to the Wizard, but there may well be a way to summon him here. If I am mortally wounded, **he'll have to come back here to save us both.**
> <sup><sub>*Supernatural* Season 10 episode 11 "There's No Place Like Home"</sub></sup>

If the Wizard knew this spell, it's possible that any surviving Good Witches could have known it as well.

The Charlies could have used any of these means to get out of Oz, or she could have used the key and broken it once on this side. The episode doesn't specify, so barring future information it's all speculation.

---

<sup>1</sup> No word on how the Wicked Witch didn't know this spell

Comment: How could I forget?

Comment: what confused me was: did good Charlie and bad Charlie come through together? That seems unlikely, but how did good Charlie get the broken key otherwise?

Comment: @Michael As I mentioned in a recent edit, it seems likely that there were other ways out of Oz. Either way, it seems pretty consistent for Dark!Charlie to have given the broken key to Good!Charlie - part of the former's messed-up attempt to be accepted by the latter

Comment: Wasn't the Wicked Witch's tongue cut out?  She probably knew the spell but couldn't use it

Comment: @Izkata That's a good point, but the spell need not be verbal; in fact all of the Oz magic (and most Faerie magic, going back to season 6's "Clap Your Hands if You Believe") that we've seen has been non-verbal

Comment: @JasonBaker what makes you think Oz magic == fairy magic?

Comment: @Pureferret A throwaway line in "Slumber Party" where Charlie says something along the lines of "Oz is part of the fairy realm"